# CaseClauseError in mix test when inserting a utc_datetime value

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix application, I have a controller whose `delete` function doesn't actually deletes the item from the database but rather archives it and inserts a `:utc_datetime` value corresponding to the datetime that the item was "deleted". Here is the function:

```
def delete(conn, %{"id" => contact_id}) do
  contact = Contact.get(contact_id)

  case Contact.archive(contact) do
    {:ok, _contact} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Contact successfully deleted.")
      |> redirect(to: contact_path(conn, :index))
    {:error, _changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "Contact deletion failed.")
      |> redirect(to: contact_path(conn, :index))
  end
end
```

This is `Contact.archive`:

```
def archive(contact) do
  contact
  |> User.changeset(%{archived_at: DateTime.utc_now()})
  |> Repo.update()
end
```

My test fails with this error: `(CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {{{2018, 9, 6}, {6, 39, 5, 659053}}}`. This is how I set up my test for the `delete`:

```
client =
  :provider_user
  |> build(
    provider: conn.assigns.provider,
    type: "external",
    billable: true,
    first_name: "client",
    last_name: "user",
    email: "client@user.com"
  )
  |> set_password("password")
  |> insert

describe "delete contact" do
  test "deletes contact with valid params", %{conn: conn, client: client} do
    conn = delete(conn, contact_path(conn, :delete, client))

    assert redirected_to(conn) == contact_path(conn, :index)
    assert Repo.get(User, client.id).archived_at
  end
end
```

If it's of any relevance, here is the getter function of `Contact`:

```
def get(contact_id, preload \\ []) do
  query =
    from(
      u in User,
      where: is_nil(u.archived_at) and u.id == ^contact_id,
      preload: ^preload
    )

  Repo.one!(query)
end
```

Comment: It probably fails at this line: `Repo.get(User, client.id).archived_at`. Please put `IO.inspect(Repo.get(User, client.id).archived_at)` right before it. I’d suggest `assert {{{_, _, _}, {_, _, _, _}}} = Repo.get(User, client.id).archived_at` might fix it.

Comment: @mudasobwa I removed that line, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Would you please post _in what line do you have an error_ in the first place?

Comment: @mudasobwa, As per the stacktrace, in this line: `test delete contact deletes contact with valid params`

Comment: The plot thickens. Do you have `setup` or `setup_all` callbacks implemented? Share these please.

Comment: @mudasobwa Okay, so in my model, I changed archived_at's type from `utc_datetime` to `date`, and it resolved the error. I still need to use `utc_datetime` though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179521/discussion-between-bargain23-and-mudasobwa).